# SQL Server ORDER BY extremely slow for XML values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, performance, indexing

I'm experiencing extremely slow `ORDER BY` operations on XML data types. Please ignore the fact that the XML in the example is flat and could be stored in a table, this is test data.

I have a SQL Server table (`ID int primary identity, body XML`) and have primary and secondary XML PATH indexes on body.

My XML in body looks like this:

```
<Doc SerialNumber="000000000000000001122222" Mfg="0" Model="DXBYCD1" AcDate="5/29/2015 9:49:27 AM" />
```

My query

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    a.ID, a.Tag, a.GD, a.Body,
    a.body.value('(Doc/@SerialNumber)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Serial,
    a.body.value('(Doc/@Model)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Model
FROM 
    Asset a
ORDER BY
    Model
```

Takes about 45 seconds to complete with 5 million records in the table.

The indexes are working because if I add a WHERE clause with `body.exist(...)` the results are almost instant (2ms).

I've had a heck of a time finding ways to improve XML indexes for fast `ORDER BY`. Any help?

**EDIT:**
It looks like the difference is *WHERE* the index is being used.

When I use this clause:

```
where a.body.value('(Doc/@SerialNumber)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') = '000000000000000000000002'
```

it takes around 90 seconds.  However, when I use this clause:

```
where body.exist('/Doc/@SerialNumber[. = "000000000000000000000002"]') = 1
```

it completes immediately.

So, I can see where SQL is taking better advantage of the indexes if the comparison is happening inside the xquery.  In my original case, the ORDER BY is happening on a value statement, and the optimizer is not taking advantage.

My updated question... is there a way to use `order by` on xpath queries to order the ending result list?

Comment: Can you add a computed column that calculates Model and index that?

Comment: Your edit shows exactly the same, as I found in the linked question in my answer. The XML index will speed up queries, where you use the full path, starting with a *single* slash and down the full line... no `*` or `[...]` or any other stuff. Other queries perform even worse than without an index... Did you read that? It's worth it...

Comment: @MartinSmith yes that is an option, and definitely allows easier reporting but blows up the insertion time, db size, etc.  We currently have a very well performing EAV implementation which may be preferred over generating computed columns for everything we may sort or filter from (we generate wide views from the EAV)

Comment: @lawrence, if db size and performance of insertion matter, you should even more think about your XML index ...

Comment: @Shnugo yes i saw the link and was hoping to find more specific information on orderby execution.  db size is actually better with XML than EAV but just barely (fewer primary/foreignkeys/empty columns).  May need to keep EAV pattern if I can't find more control over the xml

Comment: @lawrence, The point is: Using `exist()` searches for the first entry and then stops, `ORDER BY` must read all values to order them. In my example the db's size was incredibly blown up on creating the XML index. Keeping this index up to date on each DML-operation needs a lot of background work. Without knowing your actual data I cannot offer a better suggestion, but the XML index - at least for me - is something to avoid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML indexes are something really - uhm - strange...

Once I tried around and finally posted this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/130969/70663

The conclusio: If there is an XML index it will **slow** down many "normal" actions against your XML and speed up just some very rare special cases.

So my suggestion was: Let the XML index away and trigger the value(s) you want to sort/filter/search with into "normal" indexed columns, if necessary within a side table.